# Docker Setup with Complex Project Structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I can run an application through Docker if the application is just straight foreword, something like following.

Lets say I have Hello World Application written in Python/Django. And the project directory structure is

### (Ordinary format)

```
proj_directory
  - app.py
  - requirements.txt
  - Dockerfile
```

The application runs perfectly if I do the following:

```
docker build -t friendlyhello .
`docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello`
```

### (Preferred format)

HOWEVER, if I change the project directory structure like following, then it doesnot work anymore.

```
proj_directory
  - folder/app.py
  - requirements.txt
  - Dockerfile
```

According to Docker setup instructions,

> Set the working directory to /app
>
> > WORKDIR /app
>
> Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
>
> > ADD . /app

What change I should make in the Dockerfile if I want to follow my preferred format ? Not sure what but I believe I should do some changes in the above two lines in my Dockerfile. Need suggestion please.

Comment: Can you paste your Dockerfile ?

Comment: Share your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste your Dockerfile so we can help you. But I think that what you want to use is `COPY`, like this.

```
COPY folder folder
```

To maintain the file structure.

Comment: Thanks, I will write in details @wassim

Comment: What about WORKDIR then ?